# Convert to Array Some Cookie Data

Tags: php, arrays

i want to convert some Cookie Data into Array .

example

```
$cook = "lg=en; mi=ui; uo=lo; ri=ui";
```

I want to convert this data to array some thing like this :

```
Array ( 
'lg' => 'en',
'mi' => 'ui',
'uo' => 'lo',
'ri' => 'ui'
)
```

I want to convert `$cook` data an array like that as a ouput .

Please , help me . Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$cook = "lg=en; mi=ui; uo=lo; ri=ui";

foreach(explode("; ", $cook) as $v){
    $tmp = explode("=", $v);
    $return[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}

print_r($return);
```

Comment: right , your code is perfect , but should replace this line     `$return[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1]);`  to this `$return[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];`

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr1 = explode('; ',$cook);
$arr2 = array();

foreach($arr1 as $val)
{
   list($a,$b) = explode('=',$val);
   $arr2[$a] = $b;
}
```

ps: use meaningful variable names.

Answer (score 1):

If the cookie content is a pattern as `value1<separator>value2<separator>value3`, you could use `explode` function:

```
$array = explode($separator, $cook);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1=explode(";",$cook);
foreach($a1 as $a)
{
   $b=explode("=",$a);
   $arr[$b[0]]=$b[1];
}
```

$arr is your array

Answer (score 0):

What about this:
arr = "lg=en; mi=ui; uo=lo; ri=ui".split(';')

You should get rid of the extra spaces first